# how to get openerp client IP

Tags: odoo

I want to get openerp user client ip address, and in my module add some code copy from web module, as below:

```
import openerp.addons.web.http as openerpweb
@openerpweb.jsonrequest
def get_ip_address(self, req):
    wsgienv = req.httprequest.environ
    env = dict(
     HTTP_HOST=wsgienv['HTTP_HOST'],
     REMOTE_ADDR=wsgienv['REMOTE_ADDR'],
     )
    _logger.log("env:%d", env)
    return True
```

But get Error:AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'httprequest'
Pls help me ,thanks very much

Comment: did you check the type of the `req`? it seems to be a list. Update the way you call the function

Answer (score 1):

Import the request object here

```
from openerp.http import request
```

And use the following code to get the user IP:

```
wsgienv = request.httprequest.environ
print "User IP: ", wsgienv['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

It works for me

Comment: it works perfect, but its marked as "undefined variable from import:environ" in eclipse. do you know how to avoid this?